# Slight change in input makes the program go nuts

Tags: c, if-statement, input

I have this piece of code to check whether second date is earlier than the first date the program works normally when I input these with this order without commas 9,9,2021 but when I do input 09 for the first input It skips the second input and directly jumps into the third input I can't figure out why this is the case since I am fairly new to C

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Array format [DD,MM,YYYY]
int date[3];
int secondDate[3];

// ANSI color codes
#define RED "\x1b[31m"
#define GREEN "\x1b[32m"

int main()
{
    printf("Enter the day of first date: ");
    scanf("%i", &date[0]);

    printf("Enter the month of first date: ");
    scanf("%i", &date[1]);

    printf("Enter the year of first date: ");
    scanf("%i", &date[2]);

    printf("Enter the day of the second date: ");
    scanf("%i", &secondDate[0]);

    printf("Enter the month of the second date: ");
    scanf("%i", &secondDate[1]);

    printf("Enter the year of the second date: ");
    scanf("%i", &secondDate[2]);

   return 0;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%i` formar specifier is recognizing the number base prefixes (that is `"0x"` for hexadecimal, and `'0'` for octal). The `'0'` prefix is for octal. And `09` is an invalid octal, as octal numbers contain digits `0-7`.

You can use the `%d` specifier instead of `%i`, which is only interpreting decimal numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the solution